# Get JSON data from MySQL, through PHP to HTML

Tags: php, html, json

I'm having a problem getting JSON data to HTML. I use a table in MySQL, that is decode in JSON through a PHP script. In JSON lint the data is coming correctly. The code I use to get the data into a table in HTML is also working ok if I put the JSON like data into a variable. The problem comes when I try to get it from the url. Here's the code I tried to use but there is no output.

JSON:

```
  {
    "report": [{
      "Mes": "Abril",
      "Dia": "1",
      "Local": "",
      "Servicos": "52",
      "Total": "1300.95"

    }]
  }
```

CODE:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $.getJSON("http://ib.esy.es/select_comissao1.php", function(data)
    {
           console.log(data);

           var tr = data
           for (var i = 0; i < data.report.length; i++) {
               var tr = $('<tr/>');

               // Indexing into data.report for each td element
               $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Mes + "</td>");
               $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Dia + "</td>");
               $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Local + "</td>");
               $('.table1').append(tr);
           }

    });
</script>

<table class="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Mes</th>
        <th>Dia</th>
        <th>Local</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Mes
        Dia
        Local

Comment: Where is the php code? Create an array of records then send to browser `echo  json_encode($data);`

Comment: Is that console.log(data) empty? Is your javascript hosted on the ib.esy.es server? If not, you're running into CORS.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 the php code is correct. If you go to the link ib.esy.es/select_comissao1.php you all the data correctly and validated by json lint

Comment: @mkaatman what do you mean by hosting the javascript on the server?

Comment: If you are making that ajax request to a third party server (ib.esy.es, is it your server?) you are going to get CORS issues. You should see this in the console. See here: http://jsbin.com/taxeyisibo/edit?html,js,output runner:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ib.esy.es/select_comissao1.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://null.jsbin.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: why dont you use JQuery AJAX..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the function to display the data when the promise is resolved:

```
$.getJSON("http://ib.esy.es/select_comissao1.php").then(function(data)
{console.log(data);

       var tr = data
        for (var i = 0; i < data.report.length; i++) {
        var tr = $('<tr/>');

        // Indexing into data.report for each td element
        $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Mes + "</td>");
        $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Dia + "</td>");
        $(tr).append("<td>" + data.report[i].Local + "</td>");
        $('.table1').append(tr);
        }

});
```

Comment: Finally! It worked, thanks for your precious help. I've been around this for 3 days :) Thank you Jose!